# Text on Image coming separate

Tags: html, css, email, html-email, email-templates

I am working on an HTML email template which includes an image and text overlay on top. When I view view the page as an HTML website everything loads correct but when I send it as an email all the elements are separated. Following is the code used:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<style type="text/css">
    .box{
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block; /* Make the width of box same as image */
    }
    .box .PasengerName{
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 999;
        margin: 0 auto;
        left: 945px;
        right: 0;        
        text-align: center;
        top: 25%; /* Adjust this value to move the positioned div up and down */
        font-size: 17px;
        font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
        color: #004AAD;
        width: 60%; /* Set the width of the positioned div */
    }
    .box .AircraftType{
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 999;
        margin: 0 auto;
        left: 960px;
        right: 0;        
        text-align: center;
        top: 45.5%; /* Adjust this value to move the positioned div up and down */
        font-size: 17px;
        font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
        color: #004AAD;
        width: 60%; /* Set the width of the positioned div */
    }

    .box .Duration{
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 999;
        margin: 0 auto;
        left: 855px;
        right: 0;        
        text-align: center;
        top: 62.5%; /* Adjust this value to move the positioned div up and down */
        font-size: 17px;
        font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
        color: #004AAD;
        width: 60%; /* Set the width of the positioned div */
    }

    .box .Code{
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 999;
        margin: 0 auto;
        left: 1172px;
        right: 0;        
        text-align: center;
        top: 83%; /* Adjust this value to move the positioned div up and down */
        font-size: 15px;
        font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
        color: black;
        width: 60%; /* Set the width of the positioned div */
    }
    .box .BarcodeCode{
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 999;
        margin: 0 auto;
        left: 950px;
        right: 0;        
        text-align: center;
        top: 73%; /* Adjust this value to move the positioned div up and down */
        font-size: 15px;
        font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
        width: 60%; /* Set the width of the positioned div */
    }
</style>


</head> 

<script type="text/javascript">/*
    * ConnectCode
    *
    * Copyright (c) 2010-2011 barcoderesource.com (http://barcoderesouce.com/gpl-3.0.txt)
    * Licensed under the GPL (gpl-3.0.txt) licenses.
    *
    * http://www.barcoderesource.com
    */
   
           function DrawCode39Barcode(data,
                              checkDigit)
           {
               return DrawHTMLBarcode_Code39(data,checkDigit,"yes","in", 0,3,1,3,"bottom","center", "","black","white"); 
           }
   
           function DrawHTMLBarcode_Code39(data,
                               checkDigit,
                               humanReadable,
                               units,
                               minBarWidth,
                               width,height,
                               barWidthRatio,
                               textLocation,
                               textAlignment,
                               textStyle,
                               foreColor,
                               backColor)
           {
               return DrawBarcode_Code39(data,
                            checkDigit,
                            humanReadable,
                            units,
                            minBarWidth,
                            width,height,
                            barWidthRatio,
                            textLocation,
                            textAlignment,
                            textStyle,
                            foreColor,
                            backColor,
                            "html");
           }
   
               function DrawBarcode_Code39(data,
                               checkDigit,
                               humanReadable,
                               units,
                               minBarWidth,
                               width,height,
                               barWidthRatio,
                               textLocation,
                               textAlignment,
                               textStyle,
                               foreColor,
                               backColor,
                               mode)
           {
   
                 if (foreColor==undefined)
                   foreColor="black";
                 if (backColor==undefined)
                   backColor="white";
   
                 if (textLocation==undefined)
                   textLocation="bottom";
                 else if (textLocation!="bottom" && textLocation!="top")
                   textLocation="bottom";
                 if (textAlignment==undefined)
                   textAlignment="center";
                 else if (textAlignment!="center" && textAlignment!="left" && textAlignment!="right")
                   textAlignment="center";
                 if (textStyle==undefined)
                   textStyle="";
                 if (barWidthRatio==undefined)
                   barWidthRatio=3;           
                 if (height==undefined)
                   height=1;
                 else if (height<=0 || height >15)
                   height=1;
                 if (width==undefined)
                   width=3;
                 else if (width<=0 || width >15)
                   width=3;
                 if (minBarWidth==undefined)
                     minBarWidth=0;
                 else if (minBarWidth<0 || minBarWidth >2)
                     minBarWidth=0;
                 if (units==undefined)
                   units="in";
                 else if (units!="in" && units !="cm")
                   units="in";
                 if (humanReadable==undefined)
                   humanReadable="yes";
                 else if (humanReadable!="yes" && humanReadable !="no")
                   humanReadable="yes";
   
                 var encodedData=EncodeCode39(data,checkDigit); 
                       var humanReadableText = ConnectCode_Encode_Code39(data,checkDigit);
                     var encodedLength = 0;
                       var thinLength = 0;
                       var thickLength = 0.0;
                       var totalLength = 0.0;
                       var incrementWidth = 0.0;
                       var swing = 1;
                 var result="";
                 var barWidth=0;
                 var thickWidth=0.0;
                 var svg;
                       if (barWidthRatio >= 2 && barWidthRatio <= 3)
                       {
                       }
                       else
                           barWidthRatio = 3;
   
                       for (x = 0; x < encodedData.length; x++)
                       {
                           if (encodedData.substr(x,1) == 't')
                           {
                               thinLength++;
                               encodedLength++;
                           }
                           else if (encodedData.substr(x,1) == 'w')
                           {
                               thickLength = thickLength + barWidthRatio;
                               encodedLength = encodedLength + 3;
                           }
                       }
                       totalLength = totalLength + thinLength + thickLength;
   
                       if (minBarWidth > 0)
                       {
                           barWidth = minBarWidth.toFixed(2);
                           width=barWidth * totalLength;
                       }
                       else
                           barWidth = (width / totalLength).toFixed(2);
   
                       thickWidth = barWidth * 3;
                       if (barWidthRatio >= 2 && barWidthRatio <= 3.0)
                       {
                           thickWidth = barWidth * barWidthRatio;
                       }
       
                 if (mode=="html")
                 {
                     if (textAlignment=='center')
                         result='<div style="text-align:center">';
                     else if (textAlignment=='left')
                         result='<div style="text-align:left;">';
                     else if (textAlignment=='right')
                         result='<div style="text-align:right;">';
   
                     var humanSpan="";
                     if (humanReadable=='yes' && textLocation=='top')
                     {
                       if (textStyle=='')
                           humanSpan='<span style="font-family : arial; font-size:12pt">'+humanReadableText+'</span><br />';
                       else
                           humanSpan='<span style='+textStyle+'>'+humanReadableText+'</span><br />';
                     }
                     result=result+humanSpan;
                 }
                 
                       for (x = 0; x < encodedData.length; x++)
                       {
                           var brush;
                           if (swing == 0)
                               brush = backColor;
                           else
                               brush = foreColor;
   
                           if (encodedData.substr(x,1) == 't')
                           {
                     if (mode=="html")
                       result=result
                            +'<span style="border-left:'
                            +barWidth
                            +units
                            +' solid ' 
                            +brush
                            +';height:'
                            +height
                            +units+';display:inline-block;"></span>';
                       incrementWidth = incrementWidth + barWidth;
                   }
                           else if (encodedData.substr(x,1) == 'w')
                           {
                     if (mode=="html")
                       result=result
                            +'<span style="border-left :'
                            +thickWidth
                            +units+' solid ' 
                            +brush
                            +';height:'
                            +height
                            +units+';display:inline-block;"></span>';
                           incrementWidth = incrementWidth + thickWidth;
                   }
   
                           if (swing == 0)
                               swing = 1;
                           else
                               swing = 0;
                       }
   
                 if (mode=="html")
                 {
                     var humanSpan="";
                     if (humanReadable=='yes' && textLocation=='bottom')
                     {
                       
                     }
                     result=result+humanSpan+"</div>";
                 }
                 return result; 
           }
           
               function EncodeCode39(data,checkDigit)
               {
                   var fontOutput = ConnectCode_Encode_Code39(data,checkDigit);
                   var output = "";
                   var pattern = "";
                   for (x = 0; x < fontOutput.length; x++)
                   {
                       switch (fontOutput.substr(x,1))
                       {
                           case '1':
                               pattern = "wttwttttwt";
                               break;
                           case '2':
                               pattern = "ttwwttttwt";
                               break;
                           case '3':
                               pattern = "wtwwtttttt";
                               break;
                           case '4':
                               pattern = "tttwwtttwt";
                               break;
                           case '5':
                               pattern = "wttwwttttt";
                               break;
                           case '6':
                               pattern = "ttwwwttttt";
                               break;
                           case '7':
                               pattern = "tttwttwtwt";
                               break;
                           case '8':
                               pattern = "wttwttwttt";
                               break;
                           case '9':
                               pattern = "ttwwttwttt";
                               break;
                           case '0':
                               pattern = "tttwwtwttt";
                               break;
                           case 'A':
                               pattern = "wttttwttwt";
                               break;
                           case 'B':
                               pattern = "ttwttwttwt";
                               break;
                           case 'C':
                               pattern = "wtwttwtttt";
                               break;
                           case 'D':
                               pattern = "ttttwwttwt";
                               break;
                           case 'E':
                               pattern = "wtttwwtttt";
                               break;
                           case 'F':
                               pattern = "ttwtwwtttt";
                               break;
                           case 'G':
                               pattern = "tttttwwtwt";
                               break;
                           case 'H':
                               pattern = "wttttwwttt";
                               break;
                           case 'I':
                               pattern = "ttwttwwttt";
                               break;
                           case 'J':
                               pattern = "ttttwwwttt";
                               break;
                           case 'K':
                               pattern = "wttttttwwt";
                               break;
                           case 'L':
                               pattern = "ttwttttwwt";
                               break;
                           case 'M':
                               pattern = "wtwttttwtt";
                               break;
                           case 'N':
                               pattern = "ttttwttwwt";
                               break;
                           case 'O':
                               pattern = "wtttwttwtt";
                               break;
                           case 'P':
                               pattern = "ttwtwttwtt";
                               break;
                           case 'Q':
                               pattern = "ttttttwwwt";
                               break;
                           case 'R':
                               pattern = "wtttttwwtt";
                               break;
                           case 'S':
                               pattern = "ttwtttwwtt";
                               break;
                           case 'T':
                               pattern = "ttttwtwwtt";
                               break;
                           case 'U':
                               pattern = "wwttttttwt";
                               break;
                           case 'V':
                               pattern = "twwtttttwt";
                               break;
                           case 'W':
                               pattern = "wwwttttttt";
                               break;
                           case 'X':
                               pattern = "twttwtttwt";
                               break;
                           case 'Y':
                               pattern = "wwttwttttt";
                               break;
                           case 'Z':
                               pattern = "twwtwttttt";
                               break;
                           case '-':
                               pattern = "twttttwtwt";
                               break;
                           case '.':
                               pattern = "wwttttwttt";
                               break;
                           case ' ':
                               pattern = "twwtttwttt";
                               break;
                           case '*':
                               pattern = "twttwtwttt";
                               break;
                           case '$':
                               pattern = "twtwtwtttt";
                               break;
                           case '/':
                               pattern = "twtwtttwtt";
                               break;
                           case '+':
                               pattern = "twtttwtwtt";
                               break;
                           case '%':
                               pattern = "tttwtwtwtt";
                               break;
                   default : break;
                       }
                       output=output+pattern;
                   }
                   return output;
               }
   
           function ConnectCode_Encode_Code39(data,checkDigit)
           {
               var Result="";
               var cd="";
               var filtereddata="";
               filtereddata = filterInput(data);
               var filteredlength = filtereddata.length;
               if (checkDigit==1)
               {
                   if (filteredlength > 254)
                   {
                       filtereddata = filtereddata.substr(0,254);
                   }
                   cd = generateCheckDigit(filtereddata);
               }
               else
               {
                   if (filteredlength > 255)
                   {
                       filtereddata = filtereddata.substr(0,255);
                   }
               }
               Result = "*" + filtereddata+cd+"*";
                   Result=html_decode(html_escape(Result)); 
               return Result;
           }
   
           function getCode39Character(inputdecimal) {
               var CODE39MAP=new Array("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9",
                               "A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J",
                               "K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T",
                               "U","V","W","X","Y","Z","-","."," ","$",
                               "/","+","%");
               return CODE39MAP[inputdecimal];
           }
   
           function getCode39Value(inputchar) {
               var CODE39MAP=new Array("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9",
                               "A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J",
                               "K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T",
                               "U","V","W","X","Y","Z","-","."," ","$",
                               "/","+","%");
               var RVal=-1;
               for (i=0;i<43;i++)
               {
                   if (inputchar==CODE39MAP[i])
                   {
                       RVal=i;
                   }
               }
               return RVal;
           }
   
           function filterInput(data)
           {
               var Result="";
               var datalength=data.length;
               for (x=0;x<datalength;x++)
               {
                   if (getCode39Value(data.substr(x,1)) != -1)
                   {
                       Result = Result + data.substr(x,1);
                   }
               }
               return Result;
           }
   
           function generateCheckDigit(data)
           {
               var Result="";
               var datalength=data.length;
               var sumValue=0;
               for (x=0;x<datalength;x++)
               {
                   sumValue=sumValue+getCode39Value(data.substr(x,1));
               }
               sumValue=sumValue % 43;
               return getCode39Character(sumValue);
           }
   
           function html_escape(data)
           {
               var Result="";
               for (x=0;x<data.length;x++)
               {
                   Result=Result+"&#"+data.charCodeAt(x).toString()+";";
               }
               return Result;
           }
   
           function html_decode(str) {
               var ta=document.createElement("textarea");
                 ta.innerHTML=str.replace(/</g,"&lt;").replace(/>/g,"&gt;");
                 return ta.value;
           }
   
   </script>

<body>
    <div class="box">
        <img src="https://europeanpilotacademy.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/WhatsApp-Image-2023-02-24-at-11.24.15.jpeg" alt="Flying Kites">
        <div class="PasengerName">
            <h1>Name of Passenger</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="AircraftType">
            <h1>Aircraft</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="Duration">
            <h1>Duration</h1>
        </div>


        <div class="BarcodeCode">
            
            <div id="externalbox" >
            <div id="inputdata">1</div>
            </div>
             
            <br />
             
            <script type="text/javascript">
            /* <![CDATA[ */
              function get_object(id) {
               var object = null;
               if (document.layers) {
                object = document.layers[id];
               } else if (document.all) {
                object = document.all[id];
               } else if (document.getElementById) {
                object = document.getElementById(id);
               }
               return object;
              }
             
            get_object("inputdata").innerHTML=DrawCode39Barcode(get_object("inputdata").innerHTML,0);
            /* ]]> */
            </script>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Following is the screenshot of how it loads in the browser:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YiV7.png)

Following is how it loads in the email
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGyNX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Email clients mostly do not support absolute positioning.

You need to perhaps have the whole thing as a background image (but then, that would stuff up mobile viewing), or recreate it so that the right part is a table-based layout, within a two column stack.

You may well need a different design for the mobile view, and use image swapping techniques.

If you've never done this before, this is going to be very tricky. You'll need access to several different devices to test, as different email clients render it differently. I'd suggest designing for mobile, and then giving the desktop and mobile designs to a professional.

Furthermore, if it wasn't clear already, HTML email doesn't support javascript.

Comment: Is there any documentation or video I can follow in order to help me out please

Comment: Try https://emailresourc.es/